RollupError:[[plugin impound]] Nuxt3
I am upgrading my application from Nuxt2 to Nuxt3.
After upgrading and moving everything around time to run the application I get this error I have been battling with forever.
 ERROR  RollupError: [plugin impound] Vue app aliases are not allowed in server runtime. [importing #build/nuxt.config.mjs from node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.js]

Below is my dependency
`"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^1.0.2",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.4",
    "@sidebase/nuxt-auth": "^0.6.7",
    "@sidebase/nuxt-session": "^0.2.8",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.4.0",
    "mitt": "^3.0.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.13.2",
    "pinia": "^2.2.2",
    "stripe": "^12.5.0"
  }

Does anyone know where I can look to resolve this issue?
There are no aliases set up in my nuxt.config.ts.I have checked all files to be sure there are no weird import using #.

This potentially means that the problem is a plugin. If you didn't specifically update them to be compatible with 3, that's it

i got similar error too

@distin, did you find a solution to this?

use
// import { defineAppConfig } from 'nuxt/app'

in app.config.ts
This is my solution.
